# Joomla YouTube download button or Dropbox integration

Tags: video, joomla, youtube, content-management-system, dropbox

I am trying to create a website where I will add my personally recorded videos for registered users to watch and if they like it they can download it.

Here I have 2 problems:
1. I will add up to 60 videos each day and so I would require a simple way to upload and then display them rather than uploading them to YouTube and adding them to Joomla one by one.
2. Even if I use YouTube, it has no download button.

I have thought of using Dropbox instead so I would add my 60 daily videos each day in a different folder and then my Joomla Article Page could point to that specific folder and display the videos in it. Also hopefully downloading will be allowed.

I have checked out CumuluClios.org, Vimp.com, different Joomla plugins but none fulfil my requirements. I even sent an email to Commedia Joomla Extension creator without an answer yet, which was the closest extension to what I want.

I know that this might look like I am lazy and asking for answers but I have been searching for a solution without success for days now. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking, but you might be better off on the http://joomla.stackexchange.com site because it seems like you are not asking how to program this but instead asking for a ready made solution.

Comment: Its simple...I would like to have videos on a page that can be previewed but also can be downloaded...

Comment: No it's not that simple. But it sounds like you might want to make a simple component that automatically scans the folders and files  and then renders them with a download button. It really sounds like an image gallery and you could probably get one of the free image galleries and modify it to display videos and to scan Drop box or Amazon.  I think either one of those will have an api for reading the media data.

Answer (score 0):

The best plugin that I have found was Commedia. It works exactly as I want it to.

Thanks